# creating json api laravel belongstomany relationship

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I am trying to build an API with laravel, i have a shop, comment, user, food and shop_food table. i want the api to show a list of shops, each with shop information, 5 foods, comments on shop and user who gave comments.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shop extends Model

{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'shops';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */

protected $fillable =  ['name','description','address','district','city','country','lat','long','speciality'];



/**
 * Get the shop associated with the location.
 */
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

/**
 * Get the shop associated with shops.
 */
public function foods()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Food', 'shop_food',
        'shop_id', 'food_id');
}



}
```

My shop controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Shop;
use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ShopController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $shops = Shop::with('comments.user')->get();
        return response(['shops' => $shops->toArray(), 'error'=>'false'], 200);
    }
```

what do i need to do please help. Right now cos of the errors i am only able to display shop->comments->user but i need to add food to the api

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relation between Shops and Foods are available in methods... You can do something like this:

```
$shops = Shop::with('comments.user', 'foods')->get();
```

This way you get multiple relationships and when you $shop->toArray() it will show in your API... Right?